# Geth RPC running but cannot connect in Web3 nodejs

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, ubuntu

Wracking my brains here, `geth` is running the RPC as expected but I can't connect to it with `web3` I'm running like so:

```
geth --rpc --rpccorsdomain "*" --rpcapi "eth,web3"
```

I'm running this in `screen` and see in the terminal it starts running the RPC API and then continues to sync the blockchain.

I have confirmed the API is running:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"web3_clientVersion","params":[],"id":67}' http://localhost:8545
```

Which returns as expected:

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":67,"result":"Geth/v1.7.3-stable-4bb3c89d/linux-amd64/go1.9"}
```

I'm running nodejs `v6.12.3` and `npm install web3` this morning. The nodejs script I'm trying is:

```
#!/usr/bin/nodejs

var Web3 = require('web3');
var web3 = new Web3(); // returns as expected

web3.setProvider(new web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:8545'));

var coinbase = web3.eth.coinbase;
console.log(coinbase); // undefined
```

I noticed that after running `setProvider` inspecting the `web3` object I see:

```
_provider: HttpProvider { host: 'http://localhost:8545', timeout: 0, connected: false },
```

I've tried a number of other `web3.eth` API's but no luck. How can I get it connected? Have I fundamentally misunderstood something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`npm` installs the new version of the API by default now. You can check with:

```
var Web3 = require('web3');
var web3 = new Web3();
web3.version
```

If it's >1.0.0 you need to refer to this documentation: http://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/index.html

Or get the old version:

```
npm uninstall web3
npm install web3@0.20.3
```

I should not be allowed around computers.

Comment: this does not answer the question at all